# How to determine if a email address belongs to a K12 school?

Tags: language-agnostic, email-verification

A site I work on disallows using emails from K12 schools (elementary, middle, and high schools) because policy disallows users under age 18.  It is a lot of manual moderator work to verify unusual domains; the top 20 domains is something like 70% of all registrations, but the long tail is very long.  Ideally, the registration flow could identify these a large portion of these emails and disallow account creation at the registration step.

I am aware that this question is not mathematically solvable because there is no "is an educational domain" flag in the email or DNS standards, and there is no single canonical list of education email providers.  However, for the purpose of my application, the dividends in protecting users and saving moderator labor outweighs the costs.

My current thoughts:

- Maintain a whitelist of known approved email providers, and a blacklist of known education domains.
- When an account is registered, check the domain against whitelist and blacklist, and approve or deny appropriately.
- If the domain is in neither the whitelist nor the blacklist, check for certain key strings in the domain:  *.k12.*, *schools.*, *student*, *.edu, *.ac.uk.  If any of these match, add the email to the blacklist and disallow registration.
- If the domain does not match any of the preceding wildcard matches, then take the [Bozocrack](https://github.com/juuso/BozoCrack) approach:  fetch the contents of the webpage at the root domain and search it for any tells of being a K12 school.  This would include searching for phrases such as *education*, *academic*, *public school*,  *student*,  *teacher*,  *enroll*.  If more matches than threshold N are found, blacklist the domain and cancel the registration.
- If the domain is not recognized, and no page can be loaded, then mark the account to use the existing manual verification flow.  A human moderator can add the domain to the whitelist or blacklist, depending on the results of that verification flow.
- If there were no red flags caught in the domain or the page associated with the domain, allow normal registration.

Before I set about reinventing a wheel:  is there an accepted standard to determine if a domain is associated with a K12 school?

Comment: You are looking for a technical solution to an administrative problem. Maybe you should get your users to undertake that they aren't under 18 when registering. Looking for places where they might come from is futile, and it is also fallacious: you would also be excluding the teachers, the staff, the headmaster/mistress, Board of Governors, &c. You don't want to do this. Hand this back to from whence it came for reconsideration.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  If you can address the question, please write an answer.

Comment: The whole point of my comment is that nobody can address the question.